# Continuous Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup continuous deployment for my Rails project. So far I have done following steps:

1. My app is on Github.
2. I have setup Travis CI.
3. I have created staging environment. (www.staging.myappname.com)
4. I have created prod environment. (www.myappname.com)
5. I have integrated Travis CI and Github.

What I am trying to achieve.

1. Someone creates a pull request.
2. Travis CI runs the build against pull request. (this part is done)
3. Once Pull request is merged into master branch then Travis CI run the test again. (this part is done)
4. If test is green then deploy master branch to staging environment. ( I can do this by adding `deploy` section to `.travis.yml` file.
5. Run test against staging environment, if test passes then deploy master branch to Production environment. ( I don't know how to achieve this part )

I am not sure if this is a right way to do it or not. I read couple of blog post and I noticed people creating different git branch for staging and production. Is this approach needed?

Also I can easily push my code to staging environment using Travis CI but I don't know how to run test again on staging environment and push code to production. What type of test shall I run against staging environment? Shall I only focus on selenium test for staging environment?

I can used tool like `codeship` but they offer only 100 build/month for free plan where as in Travis I can get unlimited build for free plan. This is the main reason for choosing Travis over codeship.

So my question:

1. Am I on right track?
2. What type of test shall I run against staging server?
3. how to deploy from staging to production using Travis CI?
4. Do I need `staging.rb` file in my rails app? If yes then how will it differ from `production.rb` file?
5. Do I need to create different git branch for staging and production? Currently I have only master branch which I am trying to deploy to both staging and production.

Comment: To improve this post, I would ask that you consider accepting my suggested edit. The reason you put forth for rejecting it was that I'm "constantly editing all my post [sic] for points." I'd like to ask, what's the problem with earning points by improving grammar in questions on SO? Note [these guidelines on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) indicate my edit was helpful. I'm simply trying to increase clarity; I appreciate when native speakers of my second language correct me--it's how we learn and become better communicators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually people have 2 branches, one for staging/development which deploys on the staging server and one for production which deploys to the production branch

once your staging branch is tested and ready for deployment on production, you could create a pull request from staging to master (or just merge it locally and push it) and then the CI server should detect a new version on the master branch and then deploys it to the production server.